# how to add image in tkinter?

Tags: python-3.x, image, tkinter

I can't add image (gif image) to tkinter window.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
root = Tk()
def open_image():
    qr_select = filedialog.askopenfilename(title = "open")
    im = PhotoImage(file=qr_select)
    w1 = Label(window, image = im)
    w1.image = im
    w1.config(image=im)
    w1.pack(side="right")
def window_function():
    global window
    window=Tk()
    window.geometry("800x550+650+250")
    window.title("QR_Scanner")
    btn = Button(window,text = "open a gif picture",command = open_image)
    btn.pack()
    root.iconify()
    window.mainloop()

btn = Button(root,text = "open window",command = window_function)
btn.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

my error is (_tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage1" doesn't exist)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you can't see your gif in the window is that you haven't made a reference to the image so it is collected in Tkinters garbage collector. [Read More About This Here](http://effbot.org/pyfaq/why-do-my-tkinter-images-not-appear.htm). To Add a reference to the image you can do this:

```
w1.image = im
```

And add it in your code here:

```
def open_image():
    qr_select = filedialog.askopenfilename(title = "open")
    im = PhotoImage(file=qr_select)
    w1 = Label(root, image = im)
    w1.image = im #Keep A Reference To The Image
    w1.config(image=im)
    w1.pack(side="right")
```

The reason you are getting **pyimage1 doesn't exist** is because you have more than one instance the Tk and there is only meant to be 1. You have to make your window a `Toplevel()` by replacing: `window=Tk()` with `window=TopLevel()`

Comment: Sorry I didn’t notice I’ll have a look

Comment: I have edited the question, hope this resolves your issue!

Comment: thank you so much. but TopLevel() is not correct we should write Toplevel().

Comment: You are right, I must of typed it out wrong by accident.